Intergrated microsd drive not functioning on Asus ux550ve running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I'm new to linux and ubuntu so please bear with me and assume I don't know anything (because that is very close to the reality of the situation.
I have tried the solutions posted in This Thread but the problem persists.
Here are the Results of a Hardware Probe which shows the device as detected but not working.
I have also already disabled fast boot and secure boot in my system bios.
Please Help!
